# how to create Dictionary for excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

I have excel like this :

| ProductID | SomeExplanation | AnotherColumn1 | AnotherColumn2 | AnotherColumn3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 6 | A | 65465 |
| 2 | Y | 5 | B | 6556 |
| 3 | Z | 7 | C | 65465 |

I want to create Dictionary that key values(which are ProductID,    SomeExplanation,AnotherColumn1,AnotherColumn2, AnotherColumn3) and this dictionary must have  List of values (for example dictionary key : ProductId and it's values : 1,2,3 etc..) and I think there must be List that containes all dictionaries.

I am using aspose library for excel and .net framework 4.5 .

Aspose returning the it's cell values as an object.

So my first question how can create List of dictionaries, and these dictionaries must have list of values (List<Dictionary<key,List of values>>) and how to add values to this List of dictionary ?

My second question with that :  how can I fill this list of dictionaries with aspose worksheet ?

Comment: not knowing aspose, but why do want to transpose the data? I guess you want to process the data later on, so why not use a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0) or implement an own class representing a datarow, and then you build a `List<DataRowObject>` for further processing?

Comment: Yes it can be but some reasean(long to explain) I need an Dictionary :) but I almot find the answer I wil write soon as possible :) .

Comment: Okay, then... :-) Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is method that accept Aspose Worksheet as a parameter this worksheet parameter can be one of the excel files' worksheet.

I want to iterate through all cell and assign values to dictionary, and this values belong to its header(0 row and columnOrder)

For example: there is a list called `myExcelContainer` and this list is a series of Excel columns and also this columns is an dictionary that contains key of value (Excel header - for example `ProductId`) and the values [1, 2, 3] under the Excel header.

```
 public List<Dictionary<string, List<object>>> GenerateExcelDictionary(Worksheet worksheet)
        {
            var columnMax = worksheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn;
            var rowMax = worksheet.Cells.MaxDataRow;
            var myExcelContainer = new List<Dictionary<string, List<object>>>();
            var columnKeyWithValues = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
            for (int column = 0; column < columnMax; column++)
            {
                var columnName = worksheet.Cells[0, column].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                columnKeyWithValues.Add(columnName, new List<object>());
            }

            for (int column = 0; column < columnMax; column++)
            {
                var values = new List<object>();
                for (int row = 1;row < rowMax;row++)
                {
                    values.Add(worksheet.Cells[row, column]);
                }
                columnKeyWithValues[worksheet.Cells[0, column].Value.ToString()] = values;
            }
            myExcelContainer.Add(columnKeyWithValues);
            return myExcelContainer;
        }
```

this is the excel container :

```
var myExcelContainer = new List<Dictionary<string, List<object>>>();
```

But If you can improve the algortihm performance I want you to share, please.

My english not great :) .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).